# CMake wants to use ccache instead of gcc

Tags: gcc, cmake, ccache

I am trying to use `CMake` to compile a C++ project on Ubuntu, but I get this error:

```
CMake Error: your C compiler: "/usr/lib64/ccache/bin/gcc" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_C_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "/usr/lib64/ccache/bin/c++" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
```

I have gcc and everything installed (build-essential on Ubuntu), but I cannot stop cmake from doing this, except by hard-coding `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` in CMakeLists.txt, which I am loathe to do for obvious reasons. I tried installing ccache, but that had no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supposed to change `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` from within the CMakeLists. Instead you should give them at the command line when running CMake for the first time:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/path/to/g++ ..
```

Note that this value has no effect after the first run of CMake! So if you want to switch to a different compiler you will either have to delete the CMake cache or switch to a new build directory.

On the other hand, not having to specify this lengthy option for subsequent CMake runs of course also saves a lot of typing.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on your environment variables:

```
echo $CC
echo $CXX
```

if they are empty, try to set them to point to gcc:

```
$ export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
$ export CXX=/usr/bin/g++
```

Comment: I did this, then removed the contents of the build directory and tried cmake .. again, but I got the same result. Is there some caching cmake does?